# Can the upper limit in a 95% confidence interval in a Kaplan-Meier survival estimate be above 100%?

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, standard-error, kaplan-meier

I am in need of some help in understanding the 95% confidence interval for my survival estimates (Kaplan-Meier).

For example, at 1-year my estimated survival was 0.929 with a standard error of 0.069. I calculated the CI by taking my survival estimate of 0.929 +- 1.96 x 0.069. I cant really comprehend how my upper CI limit can be 1.06424? I would really appreciate some guidance on how to calculate and understand the CI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, if you use the standard method to calculate CIs in Kaplan Meier (Greenwood's formula) this can yield estimate of upper bounds above 1 (or even lower bounds below 0).

A better approach is to take the so-called *log-log* approach, calculating CIs for $L(t)=log[-log(S(t)]$. This quantity is unrestricted so the confidence interval will be in the proper range when we transform back.

All software allow you to specify the *log-log* option when calculating CIs for KM (and, by the way, all software will force the estimates between 1 and 0 even with the standard method. If you run your example say in R you will get upper bound=1.)